# Can't open HTTPS 443 Port on Amazon Lightsail VPS - Ubuntu 16.04 Base OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail

This is a fresh VPS instance created on Amazon's Lightsail. By default the SSH 22 and HTTP 80 ports are open and I'd like to add the HTTPS 443 port. In the past this hasn't been a problem.

Now, when I go to the "Networking" tab and click on "Edit" or "Add another" and select "HTTPS", it adds port 443, but I'm unable to click the "Save" button. It's basically an unclickable button. It just does nothing. If I click "edit" and then "save" it works fine but that's only before I add the HTTPS port. Is there something I'm missing?

In the past I was able to open this port before on Ubuntu 16.04 installations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: It seems the port screen is rather broken. Enter "Custom" and type in the port number manually. In this case 443 and it'll switch to HTTPS automatically.